# nuxtjs: How to deal with asyncdata inside layout template

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, asyncdata

I'm using nuxtjs to render my page on the server. To load data inside my page with asyncdata is no problem, but how can I load my data inside my default layout which includes header and footer? Because asyncdata is not available there. Should I use nuxtServerInit inside my store or there are other approaches?

gregor